# network analysis

Tags: circuit-analysis, analog

**Find the Voltage Vo, all elements are ideal. is there any violation of laws in this circuit? [image]**

Comment: Use KCL. Current flowing in from 5V flows out to ground.

Comment: but that would mean Vo is 0V and the potential across the current source is 0,is that valid?

Comment: @saurabhp Yes, it is valid. It's an ideal current sink.

Comment: Voltage across an ideal current source can be positive, zero or negative. Depending on that it may be absorbing power or generating power.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it looks like homework with no attempted solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us redraw the circuit a little bit to make it more clear

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fjXRQz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You need to find the voltage labelled \$V_0\$. There are many ways to go about this, for me I will illustrate it via Nodal Analysis. At the node \$V_0\$ we have
$$\frac{V_0-5}{1000}=-5\times10^{-3}$$
$$V_0-5=-5$$
$$V_0=0$$

Therefore we can say that the entire voltage of the voltage source \$V_1\$ is dropped across \$R_1\$ and the node \$V_0\$ is shorted to ground. Hence we can remove the current source and the equivalent circuit would be

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyu3gO.png)</sup>

As for the violation of laws in the original circuit, I would say no. However the current source was just a redundant element and we removed it by doing further analysis.

Comment: @saurabh It's also important to note that the output of this circuit is valid with any combination of component values (i.e. the circuit is not overconstrained)